# I can't store values in the database DAO android

Tags: java, android

Hi I can't store values in the database DAO android. I have User.class:

```
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey @NonNull 
    public String uid;
@ColumnInfo(name="name")
public String name;
 public User(String uid, String name){
        this.uid=uid;
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

DAO database:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDAO {
    @Query("select*from User")
    List<User> getAll();
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAll(User users);
}
```

My Dtababase class is:

```
@Database(entities = {User.class},version=1)
public abstract  class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDAO userDAO();
}
```

My code

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                                        AppDatabase.class, "user_db").build();
                                UserDAO userDao = db.userDAO();
                                userDao.insertAll(new User("11","Melany"));
                                Log.d("main_activity_uid",
                                        "ok  you are pretty");

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
```

Now my code don't store new User(i can't print "ok  you are pretty").Why?
I have another question: i know that when you store data in the database you use threads but what do threads allow you to do?

Comment: Can you show where you access your user? In your code you are only adding a user but not getting any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem is that you always create in a new database instance instead of having a singleton database.

Single instance ([source](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#7)):

```
    private static volatile WordRoomDatabase INSTANCE;

     static WordRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized (WordRoomDatabase.class) {
                    if (INSTANCE == null) {
                        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                WordRoomDatabase.class, "word_database")
                                .build();
                    }
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE;
        }
```

---

You need a thread because the `Room` database does not allow operations on the main thread to prevent blocking the UI ([source](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries))

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Can I store the data in the Room database from a fragment, or do I have to recall the Room database from the main activity? if i call the room database it gives the fragment then i don't have to use threads, right?

Comment: You can use your database in any class but no operations are allowed on the main thread. As seen in the documentation there are different ways to achieve asynchronous operations.